# Update android app on google playstore for new Android flagship devices

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I am a cocos2d-x game developer and recently uploaded app on google playstore. I have just logged in the google play store and saw a notification message "Update your app to take advantage of the larger aspect ratio on new Android flagship devices ". I dont understand what exactly this means and what changes i need to make in my app to run properly after these new aspect ratio. See the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the recent announcement at below link ?

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html

The changes are also specified in the same article. Basically you need to add a piece of code in your manifest file, if you want to take advantage of the larger screen space going to be available with newer devices with 18:9 aspect ratio.

**Code :**

```html
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

Comment: Please accept the answer. or let me know in case of any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

No device is set to be locked with an aspect ratio, I think this means if you explicitly set a aspect ration in your manifest then you should include it, but cocos2d-x does not set a aspect ration in AndroidManifest.xml